# How to reuse form on the same MVC page with the same model?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, forms

I have a built a view with a simple contact form with Name, Email and Phone. I re-use this form two or three times on the same parent page. When the user submits one of the forms, I detect the form submitted and post contents via javascript/jQuery to a database using [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper).

The problem is when I re-use the contact form on any page, the input fields will not be generated with unique IDs. This causes w3 validation to fail saying `Duplicate ID`. In this particular case, I need the page to pass w3 validation.

How would I go about solving this? I tried with `ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix` to prefix the input fields but does not really solve the problem as the prefix value is static. If I do a random prefix value, then how can I capture that in HttpPost controller?

Here is my code.

**Index.cshtml**
- with several references to `ContactForm.cshtml`:

```
<html>
<head>...</head>
<body>
....
 @{Html.RenderAction("ContactForm")}
....
 @{Html.RenderAction("ContactForm")}
....
</body>
</html>
```

**ContactForm.cshtml**

```
@model ProjectX.Models.CaseModel
@using (Html.BeginForm("SendMessage", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.TextInputFor(model => model.Name, Res.Name, new { placeholder = Res.Name } )
    @Html.TextInputFor(model => model.Phone, Res.Phone, new { placeholder = Res.Phone, type = "tel" })
    @Html.TextInputFor(model => model.Email, Res.Email, new { placeholder = Res.Email, type = "email" })
    <input type="submit" value="Send" onclick="jsSaveForm(event);" />
}

// @Html.TextInputFor MvcHtmlString helper method 
public static MvcHtmlString TextInputFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression, string title, Object htmlAttributes = null)
{
    var req = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, helper.ViewData).IsRequired;
    var name = helper.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldId(ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression));
    if (req)
        title += " *";

    string html = String.Format("<div class=\"inp\"><label for=\"{2}\">{0}</label>{1}</div>", helper.ValidationMessageFor(expression), helper.TextBoxFor(expression, htmlAttributes), name);
    return new MvcHtmlString(html);
}
```

**CaseModel.cs**

```
public class CaseModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Res), ErrorMessageResourceName = "ValidationRequired")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

**HomeController**

```
// GET
[ChildActionOnly]
[Route("~/Home/ContactForm")]
public ActionResult ContactForm()
{
    // tried this but this is a static value. 
    // ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix = "SomePrefix";

    return PartialView(new CaseModel());
}

// POST
[HttpPost]
[Route("~/Home/SendMessage")]
public async Task<PartialViewResult> SendMessage(CaseModel model)
{
   ... brevity...
   await SaveData(model);
}
```

Comment: Why you need prefixes ? are you going to insert the form in same page more than one time ?

Comment: You can always just remove the `id` attributes - `new { id = "", placeholder = Res.Name }`

Comment: @Shyju - maybe I do not need prefixes but if the same ID appears twice on the page, w3 validation will fail and it must not in this case. Also, I do some jquery client validation - e.g. is the field empty etc.

Comment: @StephenMuecke - won't removing the `id` this cause client validation to fail?

Comment: `id` attributes have nothing to do with client side validation

Comment: Yes. You should not have same id value for more than one element. But how will that happen ?Are you calling the `ContactForm` more than one in the same view ?

Comment: @StephenMuecke - okay. Then that might be a solution I guess.

Comment: @Shyju - yes, I am calling the `ContactForm` several times. (see Index.cshtml) code.

Comment: @StephenMuecke - ids are gone, page still works (yay!)- so simple :) Please post an answer and I will accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just remove the `id` attribute by setting it to an empty string in the `htmlAttributes` argument, for example

```
@Html.TextInputFor(model => model.Name, Res.Name, new { id = "", placeholder = Res.Name } )
```

although you might want to consider doing this in your `TextInputFor()` extension method.

As a side note, you extension method does not take into account the display name for your properties (when using the `[Display(Name = "...")]` attribute, and the `title` parameter is unnecessary. I suggest your code should be

```
public static MvcHtmlString TextInputFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression, object htmlAttributes = null)
{
    ModelMetadata metaData = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, helper.ViewData);
    string displayName = metaData.DisplayName;
    if (metaData.IsRequired)
    {
        displayName += " *";
    }
    StringBuilder html = new StringBuilder();
    html.Append(helper.LabelFor(expression, displayName).ToString());
    html.Append(helper.TextBoxFor(expression, htmlAttributes).ToString());
    html.Append(helper.ValidationMessageFor(expression).ToString());
    TagBuilder container = new TagBuilder("div");
    container.AddCssClass("inp");
    container.InnerHtml = html.ToString();
    return new MvcHtmlString(container.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch! :) Out of curiosity, if one would actually need `id's` being unique - how can this be achieved?

Comment: The only reason for having `id` attributes is for use in css or javascript/jQuery selectors, so you probably do not need them in your case, but there are a few options for example, creating and appending a `Guid` to the `id` generated by the helper, (but that would make them useless in terms of css or javascript selectors anyway)

Comment: As a side note, there is also a flaw in your extension method regarding the label - it will not use the value any `[Display(Name = "...")]` attribute you might apply to your properties. And the 2nd parameter in your method seems pointless. When I get a chance, I'll update the answer with how you extension method should look, including how to remove the  `id` attribute within the helper itself

Comment: My idea for further development is that I would reference some of them in jQuery or just vanilla js. Doing the `Guid`sounds like a nice idea but wouldn't you have to tell somehow the HttpPost-controller about this dynamic `Guid` like so `[Bind(Prefix=Guid here?)] CaseModel model`?

Comment: I do attribute like this: `[Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Res), ErrorMessageResourceName = "ValidationRequired")]
        public string Name { get; set; }` - this seems to work with the extension.

Comment: Again, `id` attributes have nothing to do with your server side code. A form posts back the name/value pairs of its controls, not an `id`. In your case you simply do not need `id` attributes. If you want to style your controls, or use their values in javascript, then you give them class names and use relative selectors. (and I have no idea what your mean by your last comment - my comment was about the label your generating)

Comment: I should have explained better. I would need the IDs obviously only client side - it could be extended client-side validation for additional fields or automatic ajax lookup when user enters something particular in a form field. Re last comment, if you refer to 2nd parameter -> , `...Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression` this is used for custom resx error message.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157172/discussion-between-sha-and-stephen-muecke).